# Get focus distance on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

Does anyone know of a way to get the focus distance of a photo taken with iPhone? I'm looking for an API to do this (on the fly) or way to get the information e.g. from EXIF data after a photo has been taken. So far I've had no luck. I'm willing to programmatically take a low-res photo to get its exif data but would prefer a way to read the focus distance while iPhone is in "previewing" mode.